# Openid Authentication failed: return_to does not match return URL

Tags: openid, django-socialauth, socialauth

I am trying to login to gmail using social auth (openid) in django-python. I am getting following error while trying to login to gmail:

OpenID authentication failed: return_to does not match return URL. Expected 'http://complete/google/?janrain_nonce=2012-02-21T07%3A34%3A43Z7YPbvg&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud&openid.response_nonce=2012-02-21T07%3A34%3A45ZRRUcwNRhr0lagA&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.abc.in%2Fcomplete%2Fgoogle%2F%3Fjanrain_nonce%3D2012-02-21T07%253A34%253A43Z7YPbvg&openid.assoc_handle=AMlYA9WUfaD-iijrGZb_D3EupBJ22mgGAAeRDte9ju9WJXwm9Y8V3h4g&openid.signed=op_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle%2Cns.ext1%2Cext1.mode%2Cext1.type.first_name%2Cext1.value.first_name%2Cext1.type.old_email%2Cext1.value.old_email%2Cext1.type.email%2Cext1.value.email%2Cext1.type.last_name%2Cext1.value.last_name&openid.sig=LBPO6BxhlvdsJFPUqYol46jxmow%3D&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawmhdR7EcG1qexEK5TJ7Ho1ucx0bTuxXAsw&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid%3Fid%3DAItOawmhdR7EcG1qexEK5TJ7Ho1ucx0bTuxXAsw&openid.ns.ext1=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ext1.mode=fetch_response&openid.ext1.type.first_name=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Ffirst&openid.ext1.value.first_name=paritosh&openid.ext1.type.old_email=http%3A%2F%2Fschema.openid.net%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.old_email=paritosh.singh%40joshworkz.com&openid.ext1.type.email=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ext1.value.email=paritosh.singh%40joshworkz.com&openid.ext1.type.last_name=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Flast&openid.ext1.value.last_name=singh', got u'http://example.abc.in/complete/google/?janrain_nonce=2012-02-21T07%3A34%3A43Z7YPbvg'

I tried a lot, but can't get proper solution. If anyone can give help related to this or point out what mistake I am doing it would be great

Comment: It  is working fine on my local machine but problem arises on server, I hope some problem is with deployment.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find the answer to this problem? If so, can you post your solution as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: hey jmort253 use ' FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME="" ' in your settings file.For me it worked.